# VKontakte click by element

Tags: javascript, vk

I want click by some element in VKontakte web application from JS, but it not possible.

For example I go to this application http://vk.com/app2797985. I want click by element with id: likeBlock_button_like.

Standart JS code for clicking by element:

```
javascript:document.getElementById('likeBlock_button_like').click();
```

but this code dont work with this application. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you cannot access the element is because it is inside an `iframe`. Since the iframe is from different domain, you cannot access dom elements through javascript due to [Same origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)